# pytorch adjust only certain weights with missing data

Tags: networking, tensorflow, pytorch

I am writing code for a model that encounters missing data often. Is there an option in pytorch (or tensorflow, since I haven't written the code yet so either is fine) such that only gradients and weights of existing data are computed/updated? Effectively, this is taking a smaller neural net from a maximal neural net.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Can't you just set the missing components of the input to zero?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's impossible to do what you ask. What you can do is set all `nan` to something else with smart indexing:

given

```
>>> x

    nan     -0.1
    nan     nan
[torch.FloatTensor of size 2x2]

>>> x != x

 1  0
 1  1
[torch.ByteTensor of size 2x2]

x[x != x] = 0
```

Will set all `nan` to zero.

Among the options to consider

- A constant value distinct from all other values (0 maybe?).
- Value from another randomly selected record.
- Mean, median or mode value for the feature.
- An estimate computed by another model.